# Wordpress running on 3 domains

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having one wordpress blog at http://first-website.com.
Now i have 2 new other domains.

- http://second-website.com.
- http://third-website.com.

All 3 are hosted on same panel. Now i want rest 2 website should point to main blog.
So that all below 3 linkas will be pointed to same.

- http://first-website.com/about-us
- http://second-website.com/about-us
- http://third-website.com/about-us

Now from admin when i add any new post it should also reflect to all. Can anyone suggest how can i do it? I have checked on google and found "WordPress MU Domain Mapping".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems a few months ago;

I resolved it very simple;

I set the database as common for all the websites.

Comment: But in wordpress database whole url (along with domain name) is saved for post or site url, so i guess it will conflict.

Comment: i am not talking about the url of the website, it's the connection settings for the database